# cannot be resolved to a type error when trying to make a toggle button on android

Tags: android, togglebutton

I am trying to make a toggle button for my android app

I found this help page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html
but when I copied the code to try it out, eclipse gave me the error "ToggleButton cannot be resolved to a type"

here is the relevant part of my xml.

```
<ToggleButton

    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="onToggleSMclicked"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />
```

and here is the relevant part of the code.

```
public void onToggleSMclicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
    // Enable SM
    } else {
    // Disable SM
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you import the ToggleButton class? And on another note, the first word in your xml is misspelled.

Comment: In your XML file `<toggleleButton` should be `<ToggleButton`

Comment: Thanks, I just had to import the class

Comment: Change  <toggleleButton> to <ToggleButton>